# ValueError None values not supported in _make_train_function (Keras)

Tags: python, keras, tensor

Trying to fit a model in Keras intialized and compiled as below but get None ValueErrors. What are recommended ways to debug such errors? I am new to Keras.

Can I detect the problem earlier, i.e. in initializing or compiling model?

```
model = Model((64,64,3))
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
binLoss = "binary_crossentropy"
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = binLoss, metrics = ["accuracy"])

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5b61099068d8> in <module>()
      1 ### START CODE HERE ### (1 line)
----> 2 happyModel.fit(x = X_train, y = Y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
      3 ### END CODE HERE ###

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1574         else:
   1575             ins = x + y + sample_weights
-> 1576         self._make_train_function()
   1577         f = self.train_function
   1578 
...
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    362   else:
    363     if values is None:
--> 364       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
    365     # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type
    366     # provided if possible.

ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Comment: What is Model in this case? Can you include the source code for it?

Answer (score 2):

Update Keras, because before 2.1.3, None wasn't a valid parameter for the epsilon

Answer (score 1):

Replacing opt with "adam" resolves the problem but it is unclear to me exactly why as the instruction on https://keras.io/optimizers/ suggest either should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid model construction using the Keras API. You should look at the [documentation](https://keras.io/#getting-started-30-seconds-to-keras) which has a 30 second guide showing how to build a minimal model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
# ...
```

If you are still uncomfortable with what the documentation is saying, you can start with a [tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python) that explains some of the concepts along the way.